# Use double Do loop with one using the result of the previous one every time it runs

Tags: loops, iterator, iteration, wolfram-mathematica, do-loops

I have a Do loop where I'm looking for the value of certain parameters that respect the conditions inside an If, and with those values, a run another Do to make another calculation of an expression that uses the values found previously, how can I do that for every set of value of the parameters that satisfy the condition in the first Do loop automatically go to the second Do loop and at the end, put the found values in both Do loop in the same list, here an example of what I did,

```
Do[ a={{a1,a2},{a3,a4}};                     
a1=RandomReal[{0,1}]; a2=RandomReal[{0,1}];
a3=RandomReal[{0,1}]; a4=RandomReal[{0,1}];
If[Eigenvalues[a][[1]]>Eigenvalues[a][[2]],
PutAppend[{a1,a2,a3,a4,a},"list"]],{100}]//AbsoluteTiming

dn=ReadList["list"];
```

so since I got some values on the list,

```
Do[ b={{b1,b2},{b3,b4}};
b1=RandomReal[{0,1}]; b2=RandomReal[{0,1}];
b3=RandomReal[{0,1}]; b4=RandomReal[{0,1}];
h[i_]:=Eigenvalues[b][[1]]dn[[i,1]]-dn[[i,4]]+Tr[b.dn[[i,5]]];

If[h[i]>0&&Eigenvalues[b][[1]]>Eigenvalues[b][[2]],
PutAppend[{b1,b2,b3,b4,b,h[i]},"list2"]],{i,1,Length[dn]}]//AbsoluteTiming
```

But as you can see, I have to use memory because of the "list" even when the values in there do not necessarily satisfy the conditions of the second Do loop. I don't want to use the same Do loop and put all the conditions in the same If.

Answer (score 0):

```
helper1 := With[{mA = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]},
  {mA, Eigenvalues@mA}
  ]
helper2[mA_, mB_, evsB_] := 
  First[evsB]*mA[[1, 1]] - mA[[2, 2]] + Tr[mB.mA];
Do[Module[{mA, mB, evsA, evsB, h2},
  {mA, evsA} = helper1;
  If[Greater @@ evsA,
   PutAppend[{Flatten@mA, mA}, "list"];
   {mB, evsB} = helper1;
   h2 = helper2[mA, mB, evsB];
   If [Greater @@ evsB && h2, PutAppend[{Flatten@mB, mB, h2}], 
    "list2"]];
  ],
 100]
```